# Spark SQL Group by is not working as expected

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe below where I need to group the records based on seqId,tinId,date and if atleast one of the records acct==20 i need to pull in all the records in that group and replace the eids with 4 if their eids are 0

```
+---------+--------------+----------+-----+--------+---------+    
|seqId    |    tinId     |      acct|aid  |date    |eid      |
+---------+--------------+----------+-----+--------+---------+
|      153|4513          |20        |    1|11272020|        2|
|      153|4512          |21        |    1|11272020|        1|
|      153|4512          |20        |    1|11272020|        0|
|      145|4513          |20        |    1|11272020|        0|
|      145|4514          |21        |    1|11272020|        0|
|      135|4514          |20        |    1|11272020|        0|
+---------+--------------+----------+-----+--------+---------+
```

so the final output is these three grouped sets

```
+---------+--------------+----------+-----+--------+---------+    
|seqId    |    tinId     |      acct|aid  |date    |eid      |
+---------+--------------+----------+-----+--------+---------+
|      153|4513          |20        |    1|11272020|        2|
|      153|4512          |21        |    1|11272020|        1|
|      153|4512          |20        |    1|11272020|        4|
+---------+--------------+----------+-----+--------+---------+
```

```
+---------+--------------+----------+-----+--------+---------+    
|seqId    |    tinId     |      acct|aid  |date    |eid      |
+---------+--------------+----------+-----+--------+---------+
|      145|4513          |20        |    1|11272020|        4|
|      145|4514          |21        |    1|11272020|        4|
+---------+--------------+----------+-----+--------+---------+
```

```
+---------+--------------+----------+-----+--------+---------+    
|seqId    |    tinId     |      acct|aid  |date    |eid      |
+---------+--------------+----------+-----+--------+---------+
|      135|4514          |20        |    1|11272020|        4|
+---------+--------------+----------+-----+--------+---------+
```

I have tried the below queries and they doesn't seem to work

````
val df  = spark.read.option("header",true).csv("s3://testbucket/testdata.csv")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("data")
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

val df2 = sqlContext.sql("select * from data  group by seqId, tinId, date where acct=20 having count(*)>=1")```

what am I doing wrong here ?
````

Comment: What results do you get? Can you try moving the where clause before the group by clause like: `select * from data  where acct=20 group by seqId, tinId, date  having count(*)>=1`

Comment: the logic that you have specified and the output that you are expecting does not match. Can you please verify the expected output or the logic that you need

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function to check whether each group contains acct = 20, and replace eid = 0 with 4 if that is true. No need to split the dataframe into groups:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "eid",
    when(
        max($"acct" === 20).over(Window.partitionBy("seqId")) &&
        ($"eid" === 0),
        4
    ).otherwise($"eid")
)

df2.show
+-----+-----+----+---+--------+---+
|seqId|tinId|acct|aid|    date|eid|
+-----+-----+----+---+--------+---+
|  135| 4514|  20|  1|11272020|  4|
|  153| 4513|  20|  1|11272020|  2|
|  153| 4512|  21|  1|11272020|  1|
|  153| 4512|  20|  1|11272020|  4|
|  145| 4513|  20|  1|11272020|  4|
|  145| 4514|  21|  1|11272020|  4|
+-----+-----+----+---+--------+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the required output based on the logic that you have specified you can use the window function and perform some transformations as below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = Seq((153,4513,20,1,"11272020",2),(153,4512,21,1,"11272020",1),(153,4512,20,1,"11272020",0),(145,4513,20,1,"11272020",0),(145,4514,21,1,"11272020",0),(135,4514,20,1,"11272020",0))
.toDF("seqId","tinId","acct","aid","date","eid")
//creating the definition for the Window function to partition by group columns
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("seqId","tinId","date").orderBy($"acct")
//getting the rank per partition
val roworder = rank().over(windowSpec)
//adding the rank column to the existing dataframe
val df1 = df.select('*, roworder.as("rank"))
//adding the additional column to perform transformation for the logic and dropping the columns that are not required.
val df2 = df1.withColumn("eid2", when($"acct" === 20 && $"eid" === 0 ,4)
.when($"rank" > 1 && $"acct" >= 20 && $"eid" === 0,4).otherwise($"eid")).orderBy($"seqId".desc)
.drop("eid","rank").withColumnRenamed("eid2","eid")
 display(df2)
```

You can see the output in the image below :

[image]

The output that you have shown in the question for seqId = 145 , tinId = 4514 and acct = 21 has value of eid = 4 but it should be 0 as that group does not have any record with value of acct = 20.